# Selecting Database within codeigniter - can not select database now

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to rename my database (I am using hostmonster) and now nothing is loading on my page.  I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere on this.  I renamed the database back to what it originally was and I still getting the same error and nothing is loading on my page now.  I am using codeigniter (as the title would suggest). The following error is:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to select the specified database: xxxxx

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

I go to this file and there is nothing of relevance there:

```
// Load the DB class
$CI->db =& DB($params, $active_record);
```

Do I have to completely re-install my files to the server now?  Here is what database.php looks like...

```
$active_group = 'main';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['main']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['main']['username'] = 'xxxx';
$db['main']['password'] = 'xxxx';
$db['main']['database'] = 'xxxx';
$db['main']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['main']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['main']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['main']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['main']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['main']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['main']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['main']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['main']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['main']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['main']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Obviously, I don't really use the (xxxx)'s...

Comment: what DB you try to connect? Show us your database config..

Comment: perhaps you need to delete cache

Comment: Which cache and how would I go about doing that... ?

Comment: @user1296981 Your system cache. it seems you are in local

Comment: There is no cache folder under system.  There is an empty cache folder in my application directory but that is it.

Comment: what code is in `Line Number: 346`

Comment: // Load the DB class$CI->db =& DB($params, $active_record);

Comment: you try update Privileged Users of database in cPanel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your **control panel** , go to MySQL Databases

[image: Databases as Shown on Common Cpanel]

I assumed you have already created a user , Now what **you are missing out** ... is that you **did not add** the user to the database

[image]

after adding , confirm the necessary permission , then you are good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Set `$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;`. Here **mysql_pconnect()** is disabled, So we are using **mysql_connect()**.

Answer (score 0):

**open application->config->database.php**

and set the configuration variable

```
$db['default']['database'] = 'new name';
```

Comment: I have done this, after I renamed the database.  After it didn't work, I changed it back... still broken...

Answer (score 0):

Using command prompt/terminal, type in the following from your mysql bin folder:

> mysql -u USER -h localhost -p PASSWORD DATABASENAME

See if that throws any issues at you (wrong password, wrong database name, etc..). Make sure you use the same text from your configs (copy/paste).

Answer (score -3):

I had same problem under CPanel.

It helped to set:

```
$db['main']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Please check my edit. I am not sure about `**`. If they are incorrect edit them out.

Comment: @Tempux You're right. i was trying to bold the important.